# Setup NGINX to serve to static site on the same domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

When i use this nginx configuration separately - sites open normally

```
server {

    server_name mysite.com;
    root /myblog;
    index index.html;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
}
```

```
server {

    server_name mysite.com;
    root /homepage;
    index index.html;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
}
```

How to set up the homepage by **mysite.com** in */homepage* folder, and the **mysite.com/blog** in  */myblog* folder?

folders for static sites are in different paths.

I tryed alias, proxypass to http.server, try_files $uri - and nothing helped

Comment: You can make the directory `blog` as sub-directory of the `homepage` folder.

Comment: @Luuk this option does not suit me, the sites are in different repositories. And one of them is generated by a script.

Comment: you can create a link?:   `cd homepage; ln -s someplaceToMyblog  myblog`. This will virtually move the directory, and make it accessible as a subdirectory under `homepage`.

Comment: @Luuk I tried it, only the index.html is loaded, but styles and other files that are in the same folder do not open. Read/write permissions are ok.

Comment: Try to add an extra line with the location to your myblog, something like: `location /myblog  directoryToMyblobg`.  (more info [Serving Static Content](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#static))When that does not work more info is needed about that blog...

Comment: @Luuk 
```
    location /blog {
        alias /homepage/blog;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```
I tried this, the problem remained :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255574/discussion-between-flyer2001-and-luuk).

Comment: sorry, just finally testing on my site (which I did a long time ago for the last time) fails too.... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Luuk for the idea of linking folder:

```
cd /homepage
ln -s /myblog blog
```

After a lot of trying, these are the settings I came up with:

```
server {

    server_name mysite.com;
    root /homepage;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /blog {
         index index.html;
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

}
```

And carefully **check that links** to style files (css) and resources(jpeg...) inside the **/blog** folder are **relative**

```
// Absolute paths for /homepage resources 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" type="text/css"/>

// Relative paths for /blog resources 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
```